# C++ gdb print array gives No symbol "d" in context

Tags: c++, gdb

I am trying to debug a C++ program but I face the below issue when trying to print the contents of the array.
I have declared a array of chars as below in the c++ program

```
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    char d[s.size()];
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    while(j<s.size()) {
        if(s[j] != '+') {
            d[i++] = s[j];
        }   
        j++;
    }   
}
```

I use the below commands to compile the above code and run gdb

```
g++ -g main.cpp -o main
gdb main
```

However when I debug and hit the below command in GDB I get the below error.

```
Command entered in GDB : p *d@10
No symbol "d" in current context.
```

Can you please let me know what I can do so that all the contents of the array is printed?

Comment: Can you describe a little more about how you used `gdb` to run your program to get to the point in your code that is using the `d` variable?

Comment: Hi,  
I have added these details.

Answer (score 1):

Until you run the program, there are no variables to print. For your program, you should set a breakpoint at the last line of `main`, and run the program. When the program stops at the breakpoint, you can then print `d`.

```
(gdb) list 15
10          while(j<s.size()) {
11              if(s[j] != '+') {
12                  d[i++] = s[j];
13              }
14              j++;
15          }
16      }
(gdb) break 15
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80488b9: file x.cc, line 15.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/jxh/StackOverflow/gdb/a.out
1234567890

Breakpoint 1, main () at x.cc:15
15          }
(gdb) p *d@10
$2 = "1234567890"
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to turn off compiler optimizations. [This](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Variables.html) link gives a little more detail.